# Automatically pull from Github to gitlab issue

Tags: github, gitlab, git-pull

I have an issue while pushing/pulling branches from Gitlab.local to Gitlab.com and vice-versa.

> **Inside scoop on my setup:**
>
> I have Gitlab (Community Edition v16.6.1) installed on the local
> server (it doesn't have public access) with a few repositories, each
> with multiple branches. This setup is for the developers to test their
> code changes in local environment and maintaining local repositories.
>
> We also have a Github.com with same multiple repositories and, each
> with multiple branches. It has a CI/CD pipeline setup to auto-deploy
> code in our production servers.
>
> **The Issue:**
>
> Now, I have set up Mirroring branches (Only protected branch) with
> push direction to push local branch code to Github.com branch. It is
> working absolutely as expected.
>
> But, we have a few oversease developers who also pushes code in our
> Github repositories. Now, how can I pull their changes in my local
> Gitlab branches?

**Note1:** My Gitlab server is running on local server so it doesn't have any public URL or public IP address to connect with.

**Note2:** Gitlab Community Edition does not offer Pull direction, so this option is also not available for us.

If anyone has any solution to overcome this issue, please let me know.